# String iteration and building a new coded string doesn't work

Tags: java, android

I am trying to convert a string into another, like an encryption. Basically, if my initial string is "ABC", the result will be something like "pb7gxr9b3ptwhvtc92" which is made of 3 codes, each respective to the 3 initial chars. The initial string is taken from an Android EditText and the conversion takes place when you press a certain button, then, the output is displayed into a TextView. Here is the code:

```
 eB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String textInput = editText1.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
                String str;
                StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < textInput.length(); i++) {
                        switch (textInput.charAt(i)) {
                            case ' ':
                                output.append("wus65s");
                            case 'a':
                                output.append("pb7gxr");
                            case 'b':
                                output.append("9b3ptw");
                            case 'c':
                                output.append("hvtc92");
                            ...........................
                            ...........................
                            case 'z':
                                output.append("acxdox");
                        }
                }
                str = output.toString();
                oE.setText(str);
            }
        });
```

The output is totally wrong (I posted the bellow image), it looks like I introduced an entire text not 3 characters:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtf94.png)

Can anyone enlighten me about the reason my code does not work? Thank you!

Comment: You need to put a `break;` in every `case`, otherwise all the following ones will be processed. I would also add a `default` case in order to handle any character that is not a letter or a whitespace.

Comment: Add a break on each switch case otherwise, all the cases below the matching case will also be executed.

Comment: Oh my god man, I feel so dumb, can't believe I missed that. Thanks, you should post this as an answer so I can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `break;` statement to every `case` you are handling. Otherwise the remaining `case`s below the one that matches will be run, too. That's why your resulting `String` gets that long. Make your `switch` statement like the following:

```
switch (textInput.charAt(i)) {
case ' ':
    output.append("wus65s");
    break;
case 'a':
    output.append("pb7gxr");
    break;
case 'b':
    output.append("9b3ptw");
    break;
case 'c':
    output.append("hvtc92");
    break;
    ...........................
    ...........................
case 'z':
    output.append("acxdox");
    break;
default:
    // handle the case for a char that is neither a letter nor a whitespace
    break;
}
```